# Ubuntu 16.04 wont boot without USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb

I want to use ubuntu 16.04 with windows 8.1 (dual boot) . But after installing ubuntu it only boots with a USB. after booting in the grub page it shows 4 options . they are  :-

1. try ubuntu without installing.
2. install ubuntu
3. odx installation (for manufacturers)
4. check for drive errors.

   I am now using the 1st option because after installing ubuntu this is the option that I find suitable for using.

I have installed ubuntu 2 times but nothing is working out for me.

then I saw a post which instructed me to write some codes in the terminals.

the result I got after I tried the below codes:-

```
$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-label/
total 0

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 27 15:46 RECOVERY -> ../../sda5    
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 27 15:46 UBUNTU\x2016_0 -> ../../sdb1    
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 27 15:46 Windows -> ../../sda4    
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 27 15:46 WINRE -> ../../sda1



$ sudo grub-install /dev/sdb
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `aufs'.
```

Even I am not able to access any files in my pc through Ubuntu.
it shows the error :-

```
unable to access "windows".  
Error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/ubuntu/Windows: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999" "/dev/sda4" "/media/ubuntu/Windows"' exited with non-zero exit status 1:   
Blockquote
```

I am not able to understand what is wrong and I am not able to find a solution for it. I am a new to Ubuntu so do give a bit of explanations.

Comment: Have you removed the USB after installation of Ubuntu (*Install Ubuntu*)?

Comment: no @grooveplex 
only once i did . it made the pc unresponsive.